# Laravel: Undefined variable Posts

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined

I am trying to display data using a foreach statement within my system. Now i am passing through the variable 'posts' into my view however i keep receiving the error: Undefined variable: posts (View:.

Search.blade.php

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->distance}}">{{ $post->distance}}</option>

 @endforeach
```

SearchController.php

```
     public function index()
    {
       $posts = Post::all();
       return view('pages.Search')->with('posts', $posts);

     }
```

Now in my PostsController.php i have similar code which returns all the posts.

PostsController.php

```
  public function index()
   {
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

Is this going to cause the error, i didnt think it would cause its returning to a completely separate page.

Comment: Please share your complete error

Answer (score 0):

you could probably do it this way:

```
public function index()
   {
    $data['posts'] = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('posts.index')->with(['posts' => $posts]);
```

Should do the work

Comment: As per Laravel Documentation there is not need to use array using "with"
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views
 return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');

Comment: @alicanAli hi just for you help, it will be posts.search as i am returning the search view. however i did try this and it did not work

Comment: i also took away the code in search.blade.php and just left {{$posts}} however i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in $posts in the controller

Try compact

Like:-
In Controller

```
$posts = Post::all();    
return view('posts.index', compact('posts');
```

In blade

```
@if(count($posts)>0)
 @foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->distance}}">{{ $post->distance}}. 
  </option>
 @endforeach
@else
 <h4>Data not found</h4>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the variable is passed to the correct view.

---

Troubleshooting step:

- Find the URL
- Find the corresponding route
- Find the Controller
- Find the view

Make sure that you are using the correct controller for the view.

Comment: can you explain this more, i feel this is where my error is but not sure where exactly.